# Trying to import a module by path fails

Tags: python

I have a module located in a different directory.  I want to import it in another module.  When I try to import from the directory, I get a syntax error.  How do I import other local modules?

```
from "C:\User\Sam\module" import abc
```

Comment: That's not how you import packages. You can't specify the path in the import statement.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should build and install packages [the standard way](https://packaging.python.org/).  Using a virtualenv and pip will set up your path for you, and install/symlink modules in a standard location.  If for some reason you don't want to do that, see below.

---

If the module is not in the working directory you started Python from, add the folder containing your module to the path, then import the module by name.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0'C:/User/Sam/local_modules')
import my_module
```

Modifying the path is *never* necessary if you follow the standard package guidelines.